# what is a easy way to develop a mobile web application?

Tags: spring, cakephp, jquery-mobile, mobile-website

I want to develop a small web application for mobile uses.It will have a few DB tables.
user registration, login, few simple forms with ajax auto complete boxes (will talk to database)

The options I could think were

1. cakePHP with jquerymobile
2. force.com
3. spring mobile

I know PHP, Java.

if there is any other easy (and free) solution I am open to learn that.

please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: To get a decent answer, I think you need to provide more detail about what your application needs to do. You can easily Google and find tons of PHP frameworks, mobile Javascript frameworks, etc., but to properly recommend anything we would need to know what kind of challenges need to be met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is is very subjective question. When you asking something like this, can start a sort of flamewar - so it is up to your research. :)

My point of view:

- jquery-mobie - still has few bugs, but imho it is easy, cross-platform, free, nice...
- perl especially [perl-Dancer](http://perldancer.org/)

but if you already know php - go with it... ;)